# Нужна ли запятая после слова "зачастую"?

Tags: запятые

К тому же, зачастую (?) так оно и есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна.

ЗАЧАСТУЮ — наречие. || Можно заменить на "часто", "время от времени".

Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

*…Отчего русские люди извечно жалостливы к арестантам и зачастую равнодушны к себе, к соседу – инвалиду войны и труда?* В. Астафьев, Печальный детектив.
*Смелость же Мамочкина была зачастую позерством, нуждалась в беспрестанном подстегивании самолюбия, и он понимал это.* Э. Казакевич, Звезда.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_214
https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/zachastuyu.html